# WhenEvent StopIntegration not working

Tags: differential-equations, functions

I am trying to use a WhenEvent to StopIntegration when Tmelt=1356 is reached. Although the NDSolve appears to be working, "StopIntegration" is not stopping the integration and no value is given for tliquid.

```
Est[Tp_[t_]] := ρp[Tp[t]]*Vp*cpp[Tp[t]]*Tp'[t]
Eoutliq[t_, Tp_[t_]] := (qconvliq[t, Tp[t]] + qcond + qrad[Tp[t]])
qconvliq[t_, Tp_[t_]] := hliq[t]*As*(Tp[t] - Tair)
hliq[t_] := (Nusliq[t]*kair)/d
Nusliq[t_] := 2 + 0.6*(Rey[v[t]] /. v[t] First[Evaluate[vel[t]]])^(1/2)*Pr^(1/3)
ans = NDSolve[{Est[Tp[t]] == -Eoutliq[t, Tp[t]], Tp[0] == Tpi, 
WhenEvent[Tp[t] == Tmelt, tliquid = t; "StopIntegration"]},Tp[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

The result outputs:

> {{Tp[t] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 10.}}, <>][t]}}

I am then able to graph the solution for Tp[t]. Tp reaches 1356 at about t=0.6.

I can successfully use this exact code with a slightly different (and more complex) equation for Nusliq:

```
hsol[t_, Tp_[t_]] := (Nussol[t, Tp[t]]*kair)/d
Nusliq[t_, Tp_[t_]] := 2 + (0.4*(Rey[v[t]] /. v[t] -> First[Evaluate[vel[t]]])^(1/2) + 
0.06*(Rey[v[t]] /. v[t] -> First[Evaluate[vel[t]]])^(2/3))*Pr^0.4*
(μair/(μairTp[Tp[t]]))^0.25;
```

Integration is stopped at tliquid=0.739343 and the result outputs:

> {{Tp[t] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 0.739343}}, <>][t]}}

Comment: I get errors when I run the first code block: `ReplaceAll::reps: "{t\ v[t]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing."` and `NDSolve::underdet: There are more dependent variables, {Tp[t],v[t]}, than equations, so the system is underdetermined.`

Comment: Thank you for your response Chris. Because the code is long I did include all of the variables in my original question. v(t) was found using NDSolve and is dependent on many different variables. I could post the entire code, but it is very long and detailed.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the event was missed. I was able to get it to work by changing the DetectionMethod.

```
ans = NDSolve[{Est[Tp[t]] == -Eoutliq[t, Tp[t]], Tp[0] == Tpi, 
  WhenEvent[Evaluate[Tp[t] == Tmelt], tliquid = t; "StopIntegration",
  "DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation"]}, Tp[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

The result is now:

```
 {{Tp[t] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 0.613914}}, <>][t]}}
```

and a value is assigned to tliquid.